# Inheriting PropertyInfo

Tags: c#

i wanted to extend the PropertyInfo class so that it could also contain the property value, without the need to have a reference to the original object as the following

```
public class PropertyInfoWithValue : PropertyInfo
    {
        private object value;
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public PropertyInfoWithValue(object value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

but now the problem is i get couple exceptions that

```
`PropertyInfoWithValue does not implement the inherited abstract member System.Reflection.MemberInfo/PropertyInfo.XXXX`
```

- is there a way that i could use the same implementations within
  PropertyInfo?

the way i get property info

```
 public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfoWithValue> GetColumns<T>(
                          this T obj, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] lambda)
        {
            HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(
                    lambda.Select(l => (l.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo)
                          .Select(x => x.Name)
                );

            if (set.Count == 0)
            {
                return obj.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => new PropertyInfoWithValue(p.GetValue(obj, null))).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => set.Contains(p.Name)).Select(p => new PropertyInfoWithValue(p.GetValue(obj, null))).ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Silvermind creating an ORM, and i want to make the syntax look good without having to have a reference to the instance of the object, because i could identify the object with its id property

Comment: I think it's a good thing that `Reflection` is not coupled to instances but to types. Why do you want to break that principle? What do you ultimately want to do? Because one: I don't understand what you mean by _i could identify the object with its id property_ and two: I think you're on the wrong track.

Comment: @Silvermind in PropertyInfo if you want to get the value of the property you have to have a reference to the object, all i want to do is just avoiding the need for a reference to the object, the reason is making the syntax nicer, nothing more

Comment: I would rather expect you to ask for an implementation of a `SetValue(object value)` method, because `PropertyInfo` is abstract for at least one simple reason; that one shouldn't need to create an instance of `PropertyInfo` itself, but rather get it through Reflection. So how are you getting the `PropertyInfo` in the first place?

Comment: @Silvermind i added a sample to the question, i am a noob so dont expect much i started c# couple months ago

Comment: It's okay to be a 'noob', we all have to start somewhere. But try to be more descriptive about your end goal. Because people might be able to help you make your code easier/better then to overcomplicate things. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to need to implement all methods and properties that are marked `abstract` by the base class `PropertyInfo`, but I would advice creating a custom class that reflects the data that you are trying to retreive. If you still want to return `PropertyInfo` because you think you need it, then perhaps a wrapper class would be easier to implement and understand.

Example:

```
public class PropertyInfoWithValue
{

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo;

    public PropertyInfoWithValue(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object value)
    {
        this.propertyInfo = propertyInfo;
        SetValue(value);
    }

    public object Value { get; private set; }

    public void SetValue(object value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static explicit operator PropertyInfoWithValue(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        if (propertyInfo == null)
            return null;
        // supply a default value, because we don't know it yet.
        object value = null;
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            value = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        return new PropertyInfoWithValue(propertyInfo, value);
    }

    public static explicit operator PropertyInfo(PropertyInfoWithValue
                                                 propertyInfoWithValue)
    {
        if (propertyInfoWithValue == null)
            return null;
        return propertyInfoWithValue.propertyInfo;
    }

}
```

This way you would still be able to get the `PropertyInfo` by casting it back:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)myPropertyInfoWithValue;
```